# References in a specific format with parentheses

Tags: citing

How can i cite authors who share the same idea about the same subject using the command `\cite`?

I am using these packages:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{normas-utf-tex}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[alf,abnt-emphasize=bf,bibjustif,recuo=0cm, abnt-etal-cite=2, abnt-etal-list=99]{abntcite}
```

What should be generated

> Thus, models can be classified into models in level of population, size of class or individual trees (VANCLAY, 1994, p. 6; CAMPOS; LEITE, 2009, p. 344).

Source BibTeX:

```
@BOOK{Leite2013,
  title = {Mensuração Florestal},
  publisher = {UFV},
  year = {2013},
  author = {João Carlos Chagas Campos and Helio Garcia Leite},
  pages = {605},
  edition = {4},
  owner = {user},
  timestamp = {2014.11.20}
}

@BOOK{vanclay,
  title = {Modelling Forest Growth and Yeld},
  publisher = {CAB International},
  year = {1994},
  author = {Jerome K. Vanclay},
  pages = {312},
  address = {Walligford, United Kingdom},
  owner = {user},
  timestamp = {2014.11.17}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with JabRef, so could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) to work with that we can copy-and-paste? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Include your citation packages in it as well, since solution to your question may depend on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I'm not familiar with the `abntcite` package and I don't know which bibliography style you employ. The following proposed solution is thus untested. Feedback welcome.

Assuming the `abntcite` package is compatible with the `natbib` package, you could achieve your objective as follows:

- Load the `natbib` package in the preamble (probably after loading `abntcite`);
- Issue the following citation command in the body of the document:

  ```
  ... or individual trees (\citealp[p.~6]{vanclay}; \citealp[p.~344]{Leite2013})
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, 
I am using these packages:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{normas-utf-tex}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[alf,abnt-emphasize=bf,bibjustif,recuo=0cm, abnt-etal-cite=2, abnt-etal-list=99]{abntcite}

%What should be generated
Thus, models can be classified into models in level of population, size of class or individual trees  (VANCLAY, 1994, p. 6; CAMPOS; LEITE, 2009, p. 344).
```

source BibTex

```
@BOOK{Leite2013,
  title = {Mensuração Florestal},
  publisher = {UFV},
  year = {2013},
  author = {João Carlos Chagas Campos and Helio Garcia Leite},
  pages = {605},
  edition = {4},
  owner = {user},
  timestamp = {2014.11.20}
}

@BOOK{vanclay,
  title = {Modelling Forest Growth and Yeld},
  publisher = {CAB International},
  year = {1994},
  author = {Jerome K. Vanclay},
  pages = {312},
  address = {Walligford, United Kingdom},
  owner = {user},
  timestamp = {2014.11.17}
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer but should be an edit to the original post. Please add the content to the question.